# how to call @app.before_request

Tags: python, redirect, flask, jinja2

I have a simple flask app and I want to use @app.before_request, but somehow it does not work! I am sure I am not thinking correctly about this!
apparently it will be called upon using something like:

```
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

but i need it to be called for:

```
return render_template('index.html')
```

can anybody help?

Answer (score 8):

If you would give some code maybe it will be better to understand your question, but if I understand it right you want to render template right before the request?

`before_request` is used to call some function or do some action before the request. So basically it is for preparing your app to deal with the request which comes. Example: initialize database connection and put it in `g` object for later access.

Example of before_request usage (like initialize DB for example) is:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()
```

If you use it as `@app.before_request` so it is decorator. Something more could be found in [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.before_request)

But another thing is why you want `render_template` right before request? I think that you should render templates in the views not in this place. You let the request reach your app, your view and then render template there.

Comment: Hi Ignas, I actually want to render the template after the request! I wanted the `return render_template()` to triger the `@app.before_request` as the `return redirect()` does! I get around this for now (using redirect) but still wondering if this is still doable!